# Angular router - pass url-like parameter

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

How to configure Angular 4 router to render the same component for a family of URLs that all start with the same string?

Example:

baseUrl/tree/src
baseUrl/tree/src/app
baseUrl/tree/src/app/core
...
(indefinitely deep URL starting with `baseUrl/tree/`)

I would like to then pass everything after `tree/` as a parameter to a REST API endpoint e.g.:

`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/tree?path=:path`
so for the path `src/app/core` the call will be encoded as:
`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/tree?path=src%2Fapp%2Fcore`
but in the browser URL bar I want to preserve the slashes e.g. /src/app/core

You can imaging that I'm building a file tree, similar to github/gitlab

Ideally I would like to use anchors with routerLink instead of the programmatic `router.navigate()` approach.